# Read a sub-set of NetCDF file in R

Tags: r, netcdf

Is there a possibility to read a subset of a NetCDF file in R?

In Matlab, I can use

```
ncread(filename,'WS',[i_timeseries,j_timeseries,1,1],[1,1,1,48])
```

I am trying to extract a time series from the New European Wind Atlas using free software (preferably R) on Windows.

Many thanks indeed.

Comment: I suggest searching for netcdf on https://rseek.org/ . If you code something up and are still having issues, you can raise those specific problems if not already covered elsewhere.